# How to go to the end of the loop if the a condition was satisfied in java

Tags: java, input, file-io

I have a while loop contains many statements and an if condition as well like this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
....
....

if (line.startsWith("_:"){

// I want to print this line if it starts with _: and go to the next
 //line without keep executing the rest of while loop


}

.....
.....

}
```

I tried to use break (but it will end the execution.
I tried to use continue but everything after if will be executed.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {


                final String line1 = scanner.nextLine();
                final String[] triple = line1.split(" ");


                    if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        // print uneven lines
                        writer.write(triple[0]);
                        writer.write(" ");
                        writer.write(triple[1]);
                        writer.write(" ");
                        writer.write(triple[2]);
                        writer.write(" ");
                        // writer.write(String.valueOf(similarity));
                        writer.write(" .");
                        writer.newLine();
                        break;
                    }


                    final String line2 = scanner.nextLine();

                    final String[] triplee = line2.split(" ");


                        final String subj = triple[0].substring(1, triple[0].length() - 1);

                        final String obj = triplee[0].substring(1, triplee[0].length() - 1);


                                writer.write(triple[0]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.write(triple[1]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.write(triple[2]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.newLine();
                                writer.write(triplee[0]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.write(triplee[1]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.write(triplee[2]);
                                writer.write(" ");
                                writer.newLine();




                                if (line1.startsWith("_:")) {

                                    writer.newLine();

                                    writer.write(line1);
                                                             writer.newLine();


//                                    writer.write("111111111111");


                                    break;
                                }
                                if (line2.startsWith("_:")) {

                                    writer.newLine();

                                    writer.write(line2);

                                    writer.newLine();

                                    continue;
                                }







// If any one of the previous if-conditions was satisfied
// I dont want this to be executed


                                    writer.write("<" + ResultString);
                                    writer.write(" ");
                                    writer.write("<weak_relation>");
                                    writer.write(" ");
                                    writer.write("<" + ResultStringg);
                                    writer.write(" ");
                                    writer.write(String.valueOf(similarity));
                                    writer.newLine();
                                    writer.newLine();




                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }






Actual output:
<word> <word> <word>
_:dfjsaklf <word> <word> <word>
_:lkjfdslf <word> <word> <word>
<word> <word> <word>


desired output:
<word> <word> <word>
_:fjkldsf <word> <word> <word>
<word> <word> <word>
```

**The last lines in the code are processing the line again even if it starts with _: which I dont want that to be happened. I just want to print the line if it starts with _: then go to the next line**

Comment: `if (line.startsWith("_:"){ System.out.println(line); continue; }`.

Comment: I don't recommend it, but do a Google search for Java's `goto` statement, (`label` and `continue`). And the `continue` behaviour you describe does not sound correct.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried it but it will keep executing the statements after the if-condition. I want to start the loop from the beginning again

Comment: `continue` is the command to use, but if you tried that and it didn't work, you should show us the code in question and we might be able to help figure out what went wrong. We assume that you have a `line = scanner.nextLine()` right inside the loop. Please edit question and show us what you have.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah I know goto in C++ I looked for something like that in google but did not work

Comment: @iNoah no, it won't. `continue` takes it to the next execution of the loop. Please show the code you actually tried, along with the desired and actual output.

Comment: Of course, you can avoid `continue` by putting the stuff after the `if` statement in an `else` block. (I.e. `if (line.startsWith("_:"){ System.out.println(line); } else { /* stuff to execute when line doesn't start with _: */ }`)

Comment: "If any one of the previous if-conditions was satisfied I dont want this to be executed" it won't be.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner. I will try it and let you know!

Comment: Thankssssssssss a loooot @AndyTurner. It really worked!!!!